# To praise: how to build a phrase using this word

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Distinguished visitors and creators! I have a question. A strange question:)

Due to my illiteracy I don't know how to say one thing... Well, would your native speakers' ears feel uncomfortable and confused if I said:

> "to praise IN beautiful words"

not

> "... USING beautiful words"

?!

Comment: It's hard to say without a more complete sentence.  I don't think I would ever mention _how_ I was going to praise someone.  Also, you might do better on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: They are both idiomatic, but the _correct_ use of either phrase will dependant on their respective sentence. Could you please use these phrases in a complete sentence?

Comment: Yes and you could also use *praise with…* or *… by…* or *… through beautiful words*, at least